# Specific name of this faucet / sink type

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I'm having a heck of a time finding a replacement faucet for this sink. I was hoping someone could enlighten me as to if there's a specific name for this type of sink/faucet that might help me locate one easier.

Notice the the raised area the faucet sits on the sink at, also the pieces from left to right are what looks like maybe a broken soap dispenser, a pull/push drain control for the left basin, then the faucet, then another drain control for the right basin, and on the furthest right is the hose sprayer thing (not sure of the correct verbiage for any of this).

The Sink is a 3 basin porcelain sink. The (I'll just call it a "cap") that the faucet and stuff sits on seems very unique. I understand I'll likely try to have to re-use this "cap" piece along with the original pull/pull drain plug controls for the basins, but I have no idea what you would call the rest of this setup. Everywhere I've looked I only seem to find the contemporary standard ones that sit on top of a flat surface as one piece but can't find a setup to replace this for the life of me.

So any insight would be appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is there any name or brand symbol anywhere on the sink or faucet?

Comment: The handle on the far right is a hand held spray, turn on the faucet, and push the small lever on the black handle and it will divert the water from the faucet to the spray head. Or it is supposed to. The cap is part of that sink, it will not come with the new faucet, nor will you need the one that will most assuredly come with the new faucet. If I had to guess, the functions are as follows from left to right, button (air gap) for garbage disposer or fancy plug to cover the hole, pop up drain, single lever faucet, pop up drain and hand spray. Quite unique indeed...

Comment: Nah the thing on the left is definitely a soap dispenser. If I get a chance to crawl under there in a bit I'll add an image from below....no matter what it looks like it will be a nightmare to replace either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the name of this type of sink or faucet configuration.

If you are already expecting to re-use the cap, you may be able to find another faucet that will work with it.  There are a number of one-handle kitchen faucets that are now designed to be installed with or without a wide base.  For example, the [Moen Essie faucet](http://www.homedepot.com/p/MOEN-Essie-Single-Handle-Standard-Kitchen-Faucet-with-Side-Sprayer-in-Spot-Resist-Stainless-87735SRS/206354733)

[image: Moen Essie faucet with or without base]

You may be able to take a faucet like this and mount it on top of the existing cap.

Comment: I am pretty sure the cap as it is called is or came with the sink. The single lever faucet with spray will work very well in that set up. +1

Comment: Ya I was aware of the setup but the base hole on the "cap" is an odd size. I think I may need to just try several models until I find something that fits and even then it's going to be a real pain in the butt to get it installed with that weird raised part. When you look at it from underneath I don't care how skilled you are your first thought is "Well this going to be a pain in the ***" lol, I'll accept the answer though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One handle faucets like you have are increasingly common, and they will come with mounting plates that have one, two or three (or maybe four, and apparently five) cutout holes. Look in the box.

I've not seen dual push-pull drain valves in a kitchen.  If you like these, look for a similar plate (though perhaps not with a broken soap dispenser).  If you want to be more like the rest of the planet, most kitchen sinks have drain strainer/plugs.  In that case you wouldn't need all those mounting holes.

A good home center will help you find an appropriate replacement, but think about what you want first.

Comment: This looks like a very unusual and expensive sink. I have used deep (but stainless steel) sinks with remote drain valves in a food testing laboratory. This allows draining without putting one's hand into water which may be very, very hot and have a skin damaging cleaner in it. In a residence, this might invite draining very hot water into a plastic drain system (PVC or ABS) which over time might degrade it. I do not even put batches of used pasta water down the sink (we have ABS drains) without running the cold tap.